# Android browser checkbox label not clickable

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

i am working on a responsive css menu based on the [checkbox hack](http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/fHmiI)

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="button" />
<label for="button" onclick>click / touch</label>

<div>
 Change my color!
</div>
```

css:

```
/* Advanced Checkbox Hack */

body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from {padding:0;} to {padding:0;} }

input[type=checkbox] {
 position:absolute;
 top:-9999px;
 left:-9999px;
}

label { 
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
}

div {
 background-color: #00F;
}

/* checked */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
 background-color: #F00;
}
```

which went well, valid html5 and successfully tested on both windows and linux desktops (FF, IE, Opera, Konquerer, Chrome, Maxthon), i even came up with a short (JS based) hack for IE8. when i tested on an Android 4.1.1 tablet, the menu wouldn't open, but unlike IE8 the problem is not the pseudo class `:checked` but the fact that

1. tapping the associated checkbox label does not toggle the checkbox state, and
2. a JS quick fix to simulate the click to set/unset the checkbox doesnt work as the browser sees a single [click as two clicks](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37550)

does not work on android:

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // alert(navigator.userAgent);
 $("input#button").trigger('click'); 
});
```

just to keep sane, i tested

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // alert(navigator.userAgent);
 $("input#button").prop("checked",true); 
});
```

which works, but of course only ever sets the checkbox, never unsets.

i tried a [JS workaround using timestamps](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38808#c1) but couldn't get it to work.

what puzzles me the most is that the said checkbox hack example works on that said tablet, but my menu (not published) or this simple [form with checkboxes](http://www.rpc.com.au/solar-systems/solar-street-lights/quote-request.html) does not change the checkbox on label click.

any idea where i went wrong, or how to make android 4.1.1 set/unset a checkbox without nesting the checkbox inside the label (i need multiple labels for the same checkbox)? i can live with a JS solution even though the point was to go CSS only. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i ended up using this workaround:

```
$('.touch .menu label').on('tap', function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  e.preventDefault();
  var hID = $(this).prop('for');
  $("input#"+hID).trigger('click'); /* not tap */
});
```

the tap event stems from [tocca.js](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/Tocca.js) but also works with click.

Comment: Hi thank you for this! On my Android phone, simply adding the below CSS fixed the issue with the label not opening properly.

body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from {padding:0;} to {padding:0;} }

Do you think that's all that's needed or should I add the jquery code you have to support older Android versions?

Comment: i gave up on the checkbox hack as many more issues occurred, mostly with various android devices. that css also caused a massive memory leak seen on safari browser. i ended up writing so many jQuery fixes for various problems, that i settled for a jquery menu in the end.